# Complex Integral and Substitution

Tags: complex-analysis

I have recently come across an example in my complex class where the teacher evaluated the integral of 1/(z-a) on the circle centered at the origin of radius r > |a|, with the positive orientation. The way he evaluated this was by letting w=z-a and then somehow went from 1/w dw in the integral to ire^it/re^it in evaluation to conclude the integral is 2\pi i. Can someone please explain how this substitution let us obtain the above fraction with exponents? Because that fraction is z’/z so somewhere the “-a” part vanished in z-a.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral, $\int_c \frac{dz}{z-a}$  where C is the the circle with center at the origin and radius r> |a| has a simple pole at a and can be evaluated by calculating the residue at z= a.  Here that residue is $2\pi i$.
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20more%20specifically%20complex%20analysis%2C%20the%20residue,generally%2C%20residues%20can%20be%20calculated%20for%20any%20function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20more%20specifically%20complex%20analysis%2C%20the%20residue,generally%2C%20residues%20can%20be%20calculated%20for%20any%20function)
Here it looks like your teacher is leading up to the concept of "residue" by calculating this integral directly first.

Letting w= z- a then dw= dz so the integral becomes $\int_C' \frac{dw}{w}$ where C' is now the circle with center at z= a. The integral is NOT "z'/z", it should be "w'/w" with the new variable!